# Can I be signed into iTunes with a different account than iCloud on same iPhone at same time?

Tags: itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, apple-id, itunes-store

Can my iTunes & App Store account  be separate from my iCloud, Messages,and FaceTime accounts? 
Can I be signed into iTunes with separate account from iCloud, iMessage, etc, at the same time on the same iPhone? 
Can I have a separate account (Apple ID) for iTunes purchases than my iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is what I have.

I have this because my iTunes account predates apple mail and backup which are the predecessors of iCloud. The latter had to be a @me.com address and my iTunes account was not. The usual problem is that Apple has not provided a way to combine these accounts for those who want to.

Your could have a third email with Apple for development membership. And your iTunes login could differ from your Mac apps store login but that gets too confusing.

Comment: Oh so true. I've been juggling separate iTunes & mac/me/icloud.com accounts for 20 years.